# Creating a circle with clickable dots in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to build a circle containing numerous dots that eventually will be clickable (as much as 108 dots to fill out the border of a circle).

What i have done so far is to create 108 imageviews like this:

```
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/circle_1"
        android:src="@drawable/dot_complete"
        android:layout_marginLeft="383dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="214dp"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/circle_2"
        android:src="@drawable/dot_complete"
        android:layout_marginLeft="382dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="214dp"
        />
<!-- And so on all the way up to 108 -->
```

**The result looks like this**

[image]

However i suspect this is a very bad method, so my question is what would be the better way to do this, considering i need to have onclickListener on each dot in order to show its info.

Thank you

Comment: Yes, This is a wrong method. You should be using something like [this](https://github.com/LukeDeighton/WheelView)

Comment: Thanks @SripadRaj. I have tried it out, but it seems there may be issues with it in marshmallow. At least I am unable to get anything else than a big circle

Comment: @JPJens there are few things you need to consider. Will the **whole** circle be visible at all times? Or just part of it? Are all of those images in the circle the same?

Comment: @BartekLipinski The whole circle should be visible and defaults to dot_complete, but all dots should be able to change between dot_complete/dot_active/dot_incomplete

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar class laying around, with a small modification it can display three different types of `drawables` as "dots". The only thing you would have to do is to write the `touch` management.

Drawing 108 dots (three different types):

[image]

```
public class DotsView extends View {

    private static final int dots = 108;
    private static final int dotRadius = 20;

    private Bitmap testBitmap1;
    private Bitmap testBitmap2;
    private Bitmap testBitmap3;
    private RectF dotRect;
    private Paint paint;
    private int[] dotsStates = new int[dots];

    public DotsView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setupView(context);
    }

    public DotsView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setupView(context);
    }

    public DotsView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        setupView(context);
    }

    private void setupView(Context context) {
        setWillNotDraw(false);
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);

        test();
    }

    private void test() {
        //THIS METHOD IS JUST A TEST THAT CHANGES THE DRAWABLES USED FOR SOME DOTS
        for (int i = 2; i < 20; ++i) {
            dotsStates[i] = 1;
        }
        for (int i = 50; i < 55; ++i) {
            dotsStates[i] = 2;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
        initBitmaps();
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
        destroyBitmaps();
    }

    private void initBitmaps() {
        testBitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.test_1);
        testBitmap2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.test_2);
        testBitmap3 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.test_3);
        dotRect = new RectF(0, 0, dotRadius, dotRadius);
    }

    private boolean isBitmapValid(Bitmap bitmap) {
        return bitmap != null && !bitmap.isRecycled();
    }

    private void destroyBitmaps() {
        if (isBitmapValid(testBitmap1)) {
            testBitmap1.recycle();
            testBitmap1 = null;
        }
        if (isBitmapValid(testBitmap2)) {
            testBitmap2.recycle();
            testBitmap2 = null;
        }
        if (isBitmapValid(testBitmap3)) {
            testBitmap3.recycle();
            testBitmap3 = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        if (isBitmapValid(testBitmap1) && isBitmapValid(testBitmap2) && isBitmapValid(testBitmap3)) {
            // apply padding to canvas:
            final int width = canvas.getWidth();
            final int height = canvas.getHeight();
            final int squareSide = Math.min(width, height);
            canvas.translate(width / 2f, height / 2f); // moving to the center of the View

            final float outerRadius = squareSide / 2f;
            final float innerRadius = outerRadius - dotRadius;

            final float angleFactor = 360f / dots;

            for (int i = 0; i < dots; ++i) {
                canvas.save(); // creating a "checkpoint"
                canvas.rotate(angleFactor * i);
                canvas.translate(innerRadius, 0); //moving to the edge of the big circle
                canvas.drawBitmap(dotsStates[i] == 0 ?
                                testBitmap1 :
                                dotsStates[i] == 1 ?
                                        testBitmap2 : testBitmap3,
                        null, dotRect, paint);
                canvas.restore(); //restoring a "checkpoint"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: that is perfect, and just what i need. I am still struggling to understand how i can draw a circle on top of one (or replace a circle color) by the touch event. Do i need to redraw all the dots in order to change one of the dots ?

Comment: in this code there is an array of "states" of `dots` (the `dotsStates`). So you just change the value that represents a particular `dot`. And you call `invalidate()`. This will cause the `View` to redraw itself, and based on a `state` the proper drawable will be chosen.

Comment: invalidate(); ! I was struggling to figure that out. Thank you very very much

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is super heavyweight.  I'd instead recommend making a custom View class, within which you do these things:

- Override the `onDraw` method to draw your circles directly onto the view's `Canvas`
- Implement an `onTouchEvent` listener, checking the coordinates of the touch against the positions/radii of the circles you created - thus finding the circle (if any) which was tapped
- Trigger a custom event like `onCircleTapped(View v, int circleId)` so that the containing view/activity/fragment can handle the event properly.

Comment: You are right. But I guess he may need more detail to understand what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this library[tire view](https://github.com/cenxui/Runner/tree/master/barlibrary/src/main/java/com/xenxui/mylibrary)

- import the barlibrary
- create ChartTireView

  I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks. But as there is none or very little documentation on this, it might be very difficult to get working

Comment: Or you create a class extend view and override onDraw(canvas) method use canvas.canvas.drawCircle() , almost custom views were created by that.